# TSLint object-literal-sort-keys is sorted alphabetically but error persists

Tags: typescript, tslint

TSLint is giveing me the warning `The key 'allowedHeaders' is not sorted alphabetically (object-literal-sort-keys)tslint(1)` to me this is alphabetically sorted yet tslint insists there is an error.

I also dont know how to define the callback any correctly.

What am I missing?

```
// Configure CORS
const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin: string, callback: any) => {
    if (process.env.CORS_WHITELIST && process.env.CORS_WHITELIST.indexOf(origin) !== -1) callback(null, true);
    else callback('Not allowed by CORS');
  },
  allowedHeaders: ['Accept', 'Authorization', 'Content-Length', 'Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With'],
  methods: ['DELETE', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT'], optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about string values inside of `allowedHeader`, but about properties on `corsOptions`. Regarding callback function, possible definition is `(string, boolean?) => any`.

Here is the type with both corrections:

```js
const corsOptions = {
  allowedHeaders: ['Accept', 'Authorization', 'Content-Length', 'Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With'],
  methods: ['DELETE', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT'], optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  origin: (origin: string, callback: (error: string, allowed?: boolean) => void) => {
    if (process.env.CORS_WHITELIST && process.env.CORS_WHITELIST.indexOf(origin) !== -1) callback(null, true);
    else callback('Not allowed by CORS');
  }
};
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, however the callback type is still giving me a tslint warninig `Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type. (no-any)tslint(1)`

Comment: Then you can use `(string, boolean?) => void`. I updated the answer.

Comment: `string` and `boolean?` now have these warnings `Parameter has a name but no type. Did you mean 'arg0: string'?ts(7051)
variable name clashes with keyword/type (variable-name)tslint(1)` and `variable name clashes with keyword/type (variable-name)tslint(1)
Parameter has a name but no type. Did you mean 'arg1: boolean'?ts(7051)`

Comment: Right, my bad. I fixed the signature.

Answer (score 0):

It's about the keys of the literal `corsOptions` I think. The key `option` should be placed at the end.